# Counting number of conflicting signs between two vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I have two vectors (actually 1xN matrices) that have numbers between [-1, 1]. I want to find the number of instances where the sign of two corresponding elements is not the same (sign(A[k]) ~= sign(B[k])). Is there a way to do this that's more efficient than just iterating over the two vectors?

Comment: `sum(sign(A) ~= sign(B))`?

Comment: If you're feeling playful: `nnz(A.*B<0)`

Comment: @LuisMendo - One more for the hell of it.  This is rather obfuscated:  `A = (A + 1)/2; B = (B + 1) / 2; C = accumarray([A(:)+1 B(:)+1], 1); out = C(2) + C(3);`  Nowhere near as efficient as your's and Divakar's, but just another way of completely blowing up this comments stream.

Comment: @rayryeng With `accumarray`! Hahaha, it would have never occured to me :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - hehehe I know.  Basically what I'm doing is I'm tallying up combinations of `[-1,1], [1,-1], [-1,-1]` and `[1,1]` between `A` and `B` then summing up the occurrences of `[-1,1]` and `[1,-1]` together.

Comment: @rayryeng when you have a big hammer, everything looks like a nail!

Comment: @David - ahahaha that's really funny.  That was my laugh of the day.  Thank you :)

Comment: @David: More like: sledgehammer!

Comment: @Divakar, thanks I will use this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions posted in the comments work equally well for non-time-critical computations:

> `sum(sign(A) ~= sign(B))` -- [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618048/counting-number-of-conflicting-signs-between-two-vectors#comment45539045_28618048)
>
> If you're feeling playful: `nnz(A.*B<0)` -- [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618048/counting-number-of-conflicting-signs-between-two-vectors#comment45539104_28618048)

But  the non-playful version  `sum(sign(A) ~= sign(B))` appears to be faster, presumably because it avoids multiplications involved in `A.*B`. I compared them like this:

```
Reps = 1e7; 
n = 10;
tic;
for i=1:Reps
  A = rand(1,n)-.5;
  B = rand(1,n)-.5;
  differ = sum(sign(A) ~= sign(B));   % or nnz(A.*B<0);
end
toc;
```

For the sum-of-signs version, computation time was `18.95` seconds; for the `A.*B` version, it was `47.70`seconds.